# SQL - Optimize table population with dynamic queries

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I need to optimize the following pl/sql procedure. So, fundamentally my question is: There is a way you can do a bulk insert in a pl/sql that could be more efficient than loop through an associative array?

```
type mydatatype is table of my_table%rowtype index by pls_integer;
type c_type is ref cursor;

dynamic_select  :=  'select <fields>, ';
dynamic_from    :=  ' from  <tables>';
dynamic_where   :=  ' where conditions and period_time >= ';

myobject    mydatatype;
cvar        c_type;

cursor p1 is
 select t.id, t.indicator
 from   <master_table> t
 where  <conditions>;

begin

for p in p1 loop

    dynamic_query := dynamic_select || p.indicator || dynamic_from || dynamic_where || 'to_date(''' || initial_date || ''', ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'')' || ' and period_time < ' || 'to_date(''' || end_date || ''', ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'')';

    open cvar for dynamic_query;
        loop
            fetch cvar bulk collect into myobject limit 10000;

            forall i in 1..myobject.count
                insert /*+ append */ into my_table values myobject(i);

                commit;

            exit when cvar%notfound or cvar%notfound is null;

        end loop;

    close cvar;

end loop;

end
```

My ideal would be a bulk insert like (obviously don't work):

```
insert into my_table
values      myobject;
```

I could get a boost in performance when i modified the fetch limit, but is not enough. Typically that stored procedure will loop one million times to populate the table, but is required the execution time don't exceed 1 hour. Right now the average execution time is 2 hours.

Comment: Are you saying that it will loop 1 million times each time inserting 10,000 rows so that it inserts a total of 10 billion rows?  Or are you saying that it inserts a total of 1 million rows?  Is there a reason that you're looping in the first place rather than simply dynamically constructing the entire `INSERT SELECT` statement?  Do you need the interim commits?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `insert . . . select` instead of a loop.  Something like:

```
insert into my_table
    select t.id, t.indicator
    from   <master_table> t
    where  <conditions>;
```

This isn't exactly what you need.  It is a bit hard to follow what the intermediate dynamic query is doing.